# What's the fourth step in this word problem about a pawn-shop?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

What does "a profit of 80 percent on its buy-back price" mean?

> A clock store sold a certain clock to a collector for $20$ percent more than the store had originally paid for the clock. When the collector tried to resell the clock to the store, the store bought it back at $50$ percent of what the collector had paid. The shop then sold the clock again at a profit of $80$ percent on its buy-back price. If the difference between the clock's original cost to the shop and the clock's buy-back price was $100$, for how much did the shop sell the clock the second time?

There's the initial obtain, the first sale, the first buy-back, then the last sale.

```
1. Obtain an item worth $x$
2. Collect $20%$ on the value of $x$
3. Collect $10%$ on the value of $x$ because you gained half of what they paid
4. I have no idea what this means.
```

Is this right?

Comment: The shop sold the object then bought it back.  The "buy back price" is the price at which they bought it back.  They then sold it for a second time, at $80\%$ more than that buy back price.  Thus, if the buy back price was $\$100$, they sold it (the second time) for $\$180$.

Comment: Should say, personally I don't find those hints (if that's what they are) terribly helpful.  I suggest starting by declaring a variable, let's say $P$, for the initial purchase price, then writing down all the given information in terms of $P$.

Comment: Does this clock problem need an instant answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The store bought the clock for $\$x$, sold it for $\$\frac{6x}5$ and bought it again for $\$\frac{3x}5$.

$x-\frac{3x}5= \frac{2x}5=100$ means $x=250$.

Buy-back price is $\$150$.

$150\cdot\frac95 = 270$.

Comment: Why does $x$ and $\dfrac{3x}{5}$ have opposite signs? @JMP

Comment: @user1109365  The problem says that the *difference* between the clock's original cost and the clock's buy-back price was $\$100$.